# Where is memory leak in this method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't find memory leak in this sorting method, ARC enabled. I tried to prepare an easier example with array of NSDate objects, but that one behaved normally. Where is the issue with this code? Thanks.

```
- (void)sortDataSourceByDateNewestFirst:(BOOL)newestFirst
{
    NSArray *sortedResponseEntities;
    NSArray *sortedResponseObjects;

    if (newestFirst) {
        // sort responseEntities
        sortedResponseEntities = [self.responseEntitiesObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity1, ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity2) {
            return [responseEntity2.date compare:responseEntity1.date];
        }];

        // sort responseObjects
        sortedResponseObjects = [self.responsesObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesObject *response1, ResponsesObject *response2) {
            return [response2.dateUp compare:response1.dateUp];
        }];
    } else {
        // sort responseEntities
        sortedResponseEntities = [self.responseEntitiesObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity1, ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity2) {
            return [responseEntity1.date compare:responseEntity2.date];
        }];

        // sort responseObjects
        sortedResponseObjects = [self.responsesObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesObject *response1, ResponsesObject *response2) {
            return [response1.dateUp compare:response2.dateUp];
        }];
    }
    self.responseEntitiesObjects = [sortedResponseEntities mutableCopy];
    self.responsesObjects = [sortedResponseObjects mutableCopy];
}
```

**Edit**, here is the output from Instruments:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak?

Comment: Did you run Analyzer?

Comment: @rmaddy Every time I run this, utilized memory jumps by 10 MB.

Comment: @Hot Licks No, which analyzer do you mean, do you mean Instruments? I still don't know how to use it.

Comment: the fact that the memory jumps to 10MB doesn't mean that there is a memory leak. Maybe your code just needs that much memory. How many objects are you sorting? How big are they?

Comment: @MartinKoles:Might be easier to use Instruments and follow the docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW1) and then indicate to SO if there is a problem and (if there is) where the problem exists

Comment: Click on Build, then Analyzer.

Comment: @tompave The array has 200 objects. I thought I may need memory to sort the array, but that memory should be freed on the end of the method, not added everytime I run this. With the dates example I mention above, even with one milion of Dates, memory jumped by 20 MB and then fell back to original level before the call.

Comment: Insert an autorelease block.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I ran Analyzer and it shows 3 Dead stores in the class, not in this method. How do I insert an autorelease block?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, it might be visually cleaner to call `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateUp" ascending:YES/NO] ]]`

Comment: @AdlaiHoller: Thank you, the whole method went down to 2 lines only. Much cleaner solution.

Comment: @all: There is apparently no memory leak in the sorting method, the issue is in growing allocations due to abandoned memory somewhere else..? FYI, I have collectionView with tableViews in its cells, and right after the sorting method I call reloadData on the collectionView, nothing else. I have added a screenshot from Instruments showing no leaks, but the main allocation contributor is `VM: CoreAnimation`. Also `< no-objects>` shows often with smaller memory allocation, but huge number of objects. Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you copying the arrays instead of simply assign it to your properties? Anyway in the code you posted there is no visible leak so the cases are:

**1)** Memory is simply not yet freed because the device still don't need it, the memory is marked as reusable and will be freed at the next iteration of the event loop. If this is the case simply wrapping your code in an autoreleasepool may work:

```
- (void)sortDataSourceByDateNewestFirst:(BOOL)newestFirst
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *sortedResponseEntities;
        NSArray *sortedResponseObjects;

        if (newestFirst) {
            // sort responseEntities
            sortedResponseEntities = [self.responseEntitiesObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity1, ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity2) {
                return [responseEntity2.date compare:responseEntity1.date];
            }];

            // sort responseObjects
            sortedResponseObjects = [self.responsesObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesObject *response1, ResponsesObject *response2) {
                return [response2.dateUp compare:response1.dateUp];
            }];
        } else {
            // sort responseEntities
            sortedResponseEntities = [self.responseEntitiesObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity1, ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity2) {
                return [responseEntity1.date compare:responseEntity2.date];
            }];

            // sort responseObjects
            sortedResponseObjects = [self.responsesObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesObject *response1, ResponsesObject *response2) {
                return [response1.dateUp compare:response2.dateUp];
            }];
        }
        self.responseEntitiesObjects = [sortedResponseEntities mutableCopy];
        self.responsesObjects = [sortedResponseObjects mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

**2)** You are keeping strong references to the objects held by the arrays. In this case even after the arrays are released (automatically by ARC when overriding the properties) the objects held which still have a retain count >= 1 cannot be released and thus the memory is not freed. If you don't hold anymore a reference to the object(s) referencing them then you are leaking and the objects are now zombies (and you will see them by running the Leaks Instrument).

**3)** If the object being held are custom objects maybe the leak is in the way you are adopting the NSCopying Protocol, in this case you should post the object implementation (at least the relevant methods)

EDIT: Just noticed that your properties are NSMutableArray, you can change it to:

```
- (void)sortDataSourceByDateNewestFirst:(BOOL)newestFirst
{
    //@autoreleasepool {

        if (newestFirst) {
            // sort responseEntities
            [self.responseEntitiesObjects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity1, ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity2) {
                return [responseEntity2.date compare:responseEntity1.date];
            }];

            // sort responseObjects
            [self.responsesObjects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesObject *response1, ResponsesObject *response2) {
                return [response2.dateUp compare:response1.dateUp];
            }];
        } else {
            // sort responseEntities
            [self.responseEntitiesObjects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity1, ResponsesEntityObject *responseEntity2) {
                return [responseEntity1.date compare:responseEntity2.date];
            }];

            // sort responseObjects
            [self.responsesObjects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ResponsesObject *response1, ResponsesObject *response2) {
                return [response1.dateUp compare:response2.dateUp];
            }];
        }
    //}
}
```

In this way you do not need to copy the array but you just reorder the existing ones. Anyway this will not solve your problem since, as I said, there is no visible leak here.

You should really run Instruments to find out if and where is the leak.

Comment: Antonio, thanks a lot for your detailed answer. My main problem is that I overtook an existing not ideal code and have to live with that. To answer your very first question, the property is NSMutableArray. Shall I rather remove all of its objects and add the sorted ones?

Comment: Check if the author of the code changed the default setter implementation (look for setResponseEntitiesObjects method) if not, you can simply assign the new value to the property, ARC will do the rest. So:  self.responseEntitiesObjects = sortedResponseEntities;

Comment: I tried that before, but xcode complains about assigning array into mutablearray. BTW, 1) autorelease block did not make any difference. Also, the setter is not overiden anywhere.

Comment: @AntonioE. You said *"Large arrays may with complex objects may take a noticeable amount of time to make a full copy of themeselves"*. Not really true. It's a shallow copy. Only the array is copied, not the objects.

Comment: I have replaced the mutableCopy with removeAllObjects / addObjectsFromArray with no impact. I have also added the objects implementations as per Antonio request. I think my problem is in his point 2.

Comment: @maddy You are right, probably I was thinking about NSKeyed(Un)Archiver

Comment: Declaring string, number, array, and dictionary properties as 'copy' is recommended unless profiling shows that copying is a performance problem. It makes your program much easier to reason about, and is generally plenty fast..

Comment: @AntonioE. and all: There is apparently no memory leak in the sorting method, the issue is in growing allocations due to abandoned memory somewhere else..? FYI, I have collectionView with tableViews in its cells, and right after the sorting method I call reloadData on the collectionView, nothing else. I have added a screenshot from Instruments showing no leaks, but the main allocation contributor is `VM: CoreAnimation`. Also `< no-objects>` shows often with smaller memory allocation, but huge number of objects. Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: @MartinKoles The instruments is from device or simulator? Also are you doing some fancy layout for UICollectionView? Are you drawing something in the tableviews/collectionviews? Maybe you are doing some drawing with CoreGraphics and you are not releasing object (that are not released by ARC)

Comment: @AntonioE.: It's from the simulator. I don't do any fancy stuff or any drawing or CoreGraphics in tableviews or collectionview. The only 'advanced' thing is the sync between vertical scrolling of tableviews into other collectionview cells' tableviews to keep the layout vertically in sync. I just use notifications for that, not a custom layout. I will double check if this is the issue.

Comment: @MartinKoles you should test the code on device... The simulator doesn't simulate and doesn't have the memory limit a device has. Maybe your code runs fine on a real device

Comment: @AntonioE. The vertical scrolling sync has no impact as well. I just tested on a real iPhone device and the interesting thing is that the memory issue is still present but is like 2 MB vs. 10 MB on the iPad. So I would conclude it's something with the graphics as iPhone has much smaller screen. I swear there is nothing fancy, just plain grouped tableViews inside collectionsViews, but I will dig into that.

Comment: that difference can be based on the different situations the devices have. Maybe one was requesting more memory for background apps and the other not. Anyway 10 MB, it doesn't increase too much, is acceptable.